# Why are posts allowed to be deleted without collaboration with the poster?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, self-promotion

Samuel Liew deleted [an answer I posted earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61483192/366904). But there was no reason known to me.  Nor was there any notification either.

The post I made was a reference to a blog article I wrote.

I thought Stack Overflow was trying to address rogue moderation. Doesn't seem that way with this kind of action. The minimum he could have done was contact me with some questions so we could collaborate, instead he just smashed my thoughts to offer the community.

Shouldn't closures require a reason that we can read?

Comment: [Your post](https://i.imgur.com/6oVmN8g.png) was a link to an article you wrote. 1. That's considered spam. 2. Even if you disclosed the affiliation, it's a link-only answer. Remove the link and it becomes useless.

Comment: Although, to slightly correct myself - it wasn't actually deleted as spam. It was still a link only answer, though.

Comment: There is [a topic in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) that explains why your answer was deleted. This should also be linked immediately underneath the deleted answer itself. (I can't show you a screenshot, because the reason for deletion is only shown to the *owner* of the answer.) At any rate, while it's fair to ask for an explanation of why your answer was deleted, it's not even remotely fair to assume that this is an instance of "rogue moderation". That's never been a problem on Stack Overflow, and not something anyone is trying to address.

Comment: "*The minimum he could have done was contact me with some questions so we could collaborate"* Out of curiosity what would you do to salvage this if a mod actually reached out to you to inform you that we do not allow self-advertisement (spam) on Stack Overflow? If you removed the link, then the answer would become useless. If you want to write a similar article here, which is tailored to the question you can easily do so. Mods delete hundreds of such answers every day and they don't have time to help everyone fix their "answers".

Comment: I guess I learned my lesson.

Answer (score 27):

You're referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61483192/1079354), right?

For the < 10K (and the OP who won't be able to see this in about 6 or so weeks):

[image]

We don't accept link-only answers, and the answer you provided falls apart if you just pretend that the link isn't there. (This is our standard litmus test to determine if something is a link-only answer; see: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)).

It seems to me like the primary purpose of this answer was to promote your blog. We have [a rule against this type of self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You may include a link to your blog/website as supplemental material, but you must:

1. Ensure that your answer can stand alone, even without the link (i.e., the answer to the question must be included *in the body of the post*), and
2. Provide clear disclosure/disclaimer that you own the blog/website being linked to.